# How to get colour value from cmap with RGB tuple?

Tags: python, matplotlib, colormap

For a given `val` we are able to get the RGB tuple `tup` via the following method:

```
import matplotlib as mpl

tup = mpl.cm.viridis(val)
```

here `viridis` is the default matplotlib colormap.

How do I do the reverse? I.e. get `val` from `tup`?

Comment: Can you verify the wording of your question is correct? Your first and last lines seem to be conflicting. "For a given val we are able to get the RGB tuple tup" and "How do I do the reverse? I.e. get tup from val".  The second is not the reverse of the first, it is the same.

Comment: oops sorry about that, the first line was wrong, making the change now

Comment: Although the question isn't formulated exactly the same, the main point is similar enough, so I posted my answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3720840/how-to-reverse-a-color-map-image-to-scalar-values/59897582#59897582)