# Can I reverse the process of matplotlib's pcolormesh?

Tags: matplotlib

I used python's `matplotlib` to plot my data. 
I call the numpy array before plotting as `Array1` and it looks like this:

[image: Array1].

After I called `plt.pcolormesh(t,f,Array1)`, it produced an `Image` that looks like this:

[image].

Then I read the image by calling `imread('Image')`. I got `Array2` that looks like this:

[image: Array2].

I'm confused by these two arrays, and I'm wondering how did `plt.pcolormesh` mapped `Array1` to `Array2` so I can reverse the process and get my `Array1` back from `Array2`.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to reverse a color map image to scalar values?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3720840/how-to-reverse-a-color-map-image-to-scalar-values)

Comment: @JohanC Thank you for the response but this didn't really answer my question. I will modify my question.

Comment: Well, you lose a lot of information when mapping to only 256 colors. A perfect inverse will not be possible, as explained in the suggested answer. (Probably the imaginary part is completely left out). The values in Array2 are just RGB color values (with an alpha of 1 added).