# How can I get the value in a colorbar, given the RGB?

Tags: python-3.x, matplotlib, rgb, colorbar, rgba

I have the following image:

[image: img]

Each bin has the respective RGB. Given the RGB, and a minimum and maximum value (`minv` and `maxv`), how can I convert the RGB to a value?

Comment: You can't. You need to know the exact conversion formula first.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to reverse a color map image to scalar values?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3720840/how-to-reverse-a-color-map-image-to-scalar-values)

Comment: @JohanC not quite

Comment: What do you mean by *"not quite"*? Did you try it? Which part worked? What errors did you get? What is wrong with the approaches in the linked questions, but that might work i adapted? ....

Comment: @JohanC the answers in the post you mentioned work when you do know what colormap was used, here _it seems to me_ that that info is not available but I may be wrong, maybe the OP could clarify this aspect of the problem

Comment: If you don't know the colormap, how do you expect a program to know it? Your first work should be to try to find out the colormap used.